# Numpy array documentation slicing rule

Tags: python, numpy

In Basic slicing of numpy array http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing,
I found the following rule which does not work for the example I shown below.

> **Rule:** Assume n is the number of elements in the dimension being
>   sliced. Then, if i is not given it defaults to 0 for k > 0 and n for k
>   < 0 . If j is not given it defaults to n for k > 0 and -1 for k < 0 .
>   If k is not given it defaults to 1. Note that :: is the same as : and
>   means select all indices along this axis.

**What I understood :** This can be prioritized as top to down :

> a)If k is not given it defaults to 1.
>  b)If j is not given it defaults
>   to n for k > 0 and -1 for k < 0 . 
> c)if i is not given it defaults to 0
>   for k > 0 and n for k < 0.

Now let's see the example. Basically what I am doing is to take a 3d array and print it bottom up . Layer with largest index comes first and then the smaller one. Please look at code for better understanding.

```
import numpy as np

b= np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
print "Here is the input :" 
print b
print

print "Here is what is desired output :"
print b[::-1 , :: ,::]
print 

print "Here is what I want to get desired output by a different way using above rule :"
print b[2:-1:-1 , :: , ::]
```

Output :

```
Here is the input :
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]]

Here is what is desired output :
[[[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]

 [[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]]

Here is what I want to get desired output by a different way using above rule :
[]
```

Is `b[::-1 , :: ,::]` not same as `b[2:-1:-1 , :: , ::]` by above rule?

Answer (score 2):

The document is right, but it doesn't means that you can use the calculated start, end index in `slice` object again. It only tells you the logic to calculate the start & end index. To use the calculated index, you need to generate the index by `range()`:

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
s = slice(None, None, -1)
t = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
s.indices(len(t))
```

outputs:

```
(3, -1, -1)
```

so the (start, stop, stride) of `[::-1]` for a four element array is (3, -1, -1), but `t[3:-1:-1]` is empty. The (start, stop, stride) is for `range()`, So, you can use `t[range(3,-1,-1)]` which is `[4, 3, 2, 1]`.

Comment: Slice objects are also generated when extended indexing syntax is used. For example: a[start:stop:step] or a[start:stop, i] . Pls have a look at : https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#slice ; then why t[3:-1:-1]  gives empty ?

Comment: `t[-3:-1:-1]` gives empty because `slice(-3, -1, -1).indices(4)` returns `(1, 3, -1)`.

Answer (score 1):

With a negative step, you need to think twice about the start and stop values.

A simple reverse:

```
In [437]: np.arange(10)[::-1]
Out[437]: array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

start at the end - same thing

```
In [438]: np.arange(10)[10::-1]
Out[438]: array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

with -1 stop, empty

```
In [439]: np.arange(10)[10:-1:-1]
Out[439]: array([], dtype=int32)
```

but with -2, it returns the last value; remember it's counting from the end, and -2 also counts from the end.

```
In [440]: np.arange(10)[10:-2:-1]
Out[440]: array([9])
```

last 4 items:

```
In [441]: np.arange(10)[10:-5:-1]
Out[441]: array([9, 8, 7, 6])
```

all but the first:

```
In [442]: np.arange(10)[10:-10:-1]
Out[442]: array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

same with 0:

```
In [445]: np.arange(10)[10:0:-1]
Out[445]: array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

you have to use None to get everything:

```
In [446]: np.arange(10)[10:None:-1]
Out[446]: array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```